# how do you send the id to an action in react js redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have 2 different API responses, first I get an id for a category and the second I get a list of categories based on the id category I just got, how do I send that id into action? so that the list can be directly obtained
and is there a more effective way besides the way that I have done? thanks a lot

this is action my category

```
export const getArticleCategory = () => {

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(initDataStarted());
    api.get('api/article_category/list')
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({
          type: appConstants.GET_ARTICLE_CATEGORY,
          payload: {
            articleCategory: res.data.data
          }
        })

        res.data.data.map((byIyd) => {
          return api.get(`api/article/list?category_id=${byIyd.id}`)
            .then((response) => {
              dispatch({
                type: appConstants.GET_ARTICLE,
                payload: {
                  article: response.data.data
                }
              })
            })
        })
      })
  }
}
```

and this is my page assuming you already get the data category and list category by ID

```
const Article = (props) => {

  const {
    getArticleCategory,
    listArticleByCategory,
    articleCategory

  } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (articleCategory.articleCategory.length < 1) {
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Banner />
      <Container className='py-5'>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12}>
            {articleCategory.articleCategory.map(res => {

              return (
                <>
                  <h1 className="dots pl-3 mb-5" key={res.id}>{res.category} {res.id}</h1>
                  {listArticleByCategory.dataArticle.map(item => {
                    return (
                      <CardNews
                        key={item.id}
                        title={item.title}
                        content={item.content}
                        image={item.image}
                        category={{ ...item.category }}
                        url='/detail/article'
                        type='article'
                      />
                    )
                  })}
                </>
              )
            })}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </Layout>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  articleCategory: state.articleCategory
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchArticleByCategory,
  getArticleCategory
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Article);
```

and this is reducer category

```
export const reducerArticleCategory = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case appConstants.GET_ARTICLE_CATEGORY :
      return {
        ...state,
        loading:false,
        articleCategory:[...action.payload.articleCategory]
      };
    case appConstants.INIT_DATA :
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: !state.loading
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

and this is reducer article by category

```
export const reducerArticle = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case appConstants.GET_ARTICLE :
      return {
        ...state,
        loading:false,
        dataArticle:[...action.payload.article]
      };
    case appConstants.INIT_DATA :
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: !state.loading
      }
    default: 
      return state;
  }
}
```

Essentially when I get the category_id I send it as a parameter into the list / category api

Comment: `fetchArticleByCategory(res.id)` doesn't work for you?

Comment: because I think when the id is able and thrown to the fetchArticleByCategory action, it starts immediately

Comment: You can use async await method and call the actions one after one to get your desiered results.

Comment: @ArunkumarK please give a example for it

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch 2 actions as the following

```
export const getArticleCategory = () => {
return dispatch => {
    dispatch(initDataStarted());
    api.get('api/article_category/list')
      .then((res) => {
        const { data: articleCategory } = red.data;
        dispatch({ type: appConstants.GET_ARTICLE_CATEGORY, payload: { articleCategory 
     } });
        dispatch(getCategories(articleCategory));
      })
  }
};

const getCategories = (categoryId) => {
    return dispatch => {
        // api request
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not work TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Comment: I think you have some bad redux configuration... look this simple example: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-huc2w?file=/src/App.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62342780/how-to-send-value-to-action-redux-in-react-hooks?noredirect=1#comment110258595_62342780

Comment: hi bruno, thank you very much for giving advice to the case yesterday, now I have a new problem can you give input to the problem I'm facing in redux? thank you