# how to send value to action redux in react hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a fetchLatest (limit, page) action, how do I send param to the fetchLatest function when the more load button is clicked?

this is an example of an action with the fetchLatest function (page, limit)

```
export const fetchLatest = (page, limit) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(initDataStarted())
    api.get(`web/article/filterBy/lastest?page=${page}&limit=${limit}`)
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch({
          type: appConstants.GET_LATEST,
          payload: { latest: res.data.data }
        })
      })
  }
}
```

reducer Latest

```
const initialState = {
  dataLatest: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null
};

export const reducerLatest = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case appConstants.GET_LATEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        dataLatest: [...action.payload.latest]
      }
    case appConstants.INIT_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: !state.loading
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

and this is an example of the Home page

```
import {
  fetchLatest,
  fetchPopular
} from '../modules/redux/actions'

const Home = ({ listLatest, listPopular, fetchLatest, fetchPopular }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    if (listLatest.dataLatest.length < 1 && listPopular.dataPopular.length < 1) {
      fetchLatest(3)
      fetchPopular()
    }
  }, [listLatest.dataLatest, listPopular.dataPopular, fetchLatest, fetchPopular])

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Banner />
      <Container className='pt-5 pb-5'>
        <Col className='p-0 mb-3'>
          <Col xs={12} className='pl-0 mb-5'>
            <h1 className='dots mb-3 mt-4'>Latest</h1>
          </Col>
          <Row>
            {listLatest.dataLatest.map((item) => {
              return (
                <Col md={4} className='p-0' key={item.id}>
                  <CardNews
                    id={item.id}
                    key={item.id}
                    title={item.title}
                    content={item.content}
                    image={item.image}
                    category={[...item.tags]}
                    styleImg='img-card-rounded'
                    url='/detail/article'
                    type='article'
                  />
                </Col>
              )
            })}
            <Col xs={12} className='text-center mb-5'>
              <ButtonActions title='Load more' onClick={...}/>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Col>
      </Container>
    </Layout>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  listLatest: state.listLatest,
  listPopular: state.listPopular
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchLatest,
  fetchPopular
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
```

This is a json example of API along with the URL

```
this example url {{GATEWAY}}web/article/filterBy/lastest?page=1&limit=1

{
    "message": "Success Get Article !",
    "success": "true",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 23,
            "company_id": 1,
            "title": "cara menghindar dari azab kubur",
            "content": "<p>jangan meninggal</p>",
            "image": "http://104.248.149.236/qwerty/forum/service/gateway/public/UploadedFile/Article/1591081717_photo.png",
            "tags": [
                "tips",
                "trick"
            ],
            "views": 70,
            "category": {
                "id": 1,
                "category": "Tips & Trick",
                "company_id": 1,
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "total_items": 14,
        "total_page": 14,
        "next_page_url": "/article/lastest?page=2&limit=1",
        "prev_page_url": ""
    }
}
```

Comment: It was a pain to find the "more button" you speak of in that code dump of a question but I assume it's `ButtonActions`, if it is then you can do: `onClick={()=>fetchLatest(arg1,arg2)}`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to load **more** (and not to load **new in place of old**), you should change your reducer:

reducer Latest

`dataLatest: [...state.dataLatest, ...action.payload.latest]`

In the Home component, you can create state field with the current page number:

`const [page, setPage] = useState(0);`

As `onClick` pass `onClick={() => setPage(prevPage => prevPage += 1)}`. It will increment the current page value each time the button is clicked.

And change your `useEffect` to:

```html
useEffect(() => {
  fetchLatest(page, 20);
}, [page, fetchLatest]);
```

So it will run initially and each time the `page` is changed.

If you need to change a `limit` - create a state field for it as well.